# Change TextBox Size on asp.net MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have this input on my View :

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Detail, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Detail)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Detail)
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to increase the text box width. I have changed col-md-x value but nothing changed. How can I change the textbox width for this part of code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a textbox and use the style attribute along with the **new** keyword as the example shows below

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Detail, new { style = "width:600px" })
```

It can also be used for LabelFor

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Detail, "Detail", new { @class = "control-label col-md-4", style = "width:160px" })
```

Answer (score 2):

`col-md-x` is the space allocated to the container of your textbox. You can't increase the textbox's size by increasing the class `col-md-x`, but only the container's size.

If you are using ASP.NET MVC 5.1, you can use :

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Detail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "largeTextBox" } })
```

And in your `.css`

```
.largeTextBox {
    50px;
}
```

If you are using an older version of ASP.NET MVC, you should use `@Html.TextBoxFor` instead of `@Html.EditorFor`. This supports HTML attributes.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Detail, new { @class = "largeTextBox" }, })
```

More information, see the [What's New](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes#new-features) section

Comment: Note that Html.EditorFor doesn't allow you to set HTML attributes. You can use Html.TextBoxFor instead, or use an EditorTemplate .

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the various `col-` classes as needed rather than creating a custom class.  Using these will ensure the site remains responsive - see http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes

You can specify the class by adding

```
new { @class = "col-md-3"}
```

which results in

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Detail, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Detail, new { @class = "col-md-3"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Detail)
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an object of `HtmlAttributes` with the `TextBox` using **`new`** Keyword as

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Detail, new { @class = "widthNew" });
```

and Now your css as

```
.widthNew{
    100px;
}
```